# Alt + key doesn't work in applications

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

When I trying to use some key combinations with Alt key, it doesn't work.
e.g. in Double Commander I want to search with Alt + f7 key, but when I'm press Alb + f7 it doesn't open search dialog.
Same with other apps, e.g. Intellig Idea Alt + f6 should open rename dialog, but it doesn't.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 17 and found out that the system keyboard settings assign Alt+F7 to "Move window" action, so DoubleCommander has no chance to use this shortcut for itself.
After reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts I understood that one can change it if reassign the "Move window" action to some other shortcut. E.g. go to Settings->Devices->Keyboard, find "Move window" and click on it once -> you are asked to press some shortcut you want to use for this action, I wanted to make it Alt+F6 so it asked me if I want to replace because Alt+F6 was actually configured for "Switch windows of an app directly" which I've never used though. After I did it the Alt+F7 shortcut became free to be used by DoubleCommander and I guess all other applications:)